# Discord.js dynamic command handler not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I followed the [dynamic command handler guide on the discord.js guide site](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/), and it turns out every time I try to let it execute a command, it says that the execute function is undefined, no matter how I tried to fix it. **To make sure that my code is supposed to be working, I downloaded the example code they had on the guide and ran it, which also didn’t work for some reason.** My discord.js and node.js are all up to date.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pls show some parts of code. `bot on message`, `command file execute` `command handle from dir at bot start`

Comment: @Cipher I didn't have the code but I will find the one I tested later on Github for you

Comment: I don't have the code right now but this is the code that I have tested later which also doesn't work([github](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/master/code-samples/command-handling/dynamic-commands/11/))

Comment: what is the version of discord.js you are using?

Comment: can you also add your traceback / error log?

Comment: @JackRed I am using the latest one from npm which is 1.11 I think. When I used the example code from discord.js to test, the bot doesn’t respond to anything, and no logs at all except for the “Ready!” when the bot connects to discord.

Comment: Well, I really need your code. I can't help you debug it without. The example code in the guide works fine so it's most likely an issue with either your code, your config.json or your system but I can't say without more information

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not know your current files/code, I can provide an example.
Also, in this example, I will be assuming that you have named your bot variable `client`.

- First, make sure you have a folder named `commands`.
- On the top of your bot code (`index.js` or whatever it's called), add this line:
  `const fs = require("fs");`
- In your bot code, after the bot definition (`var client = new Discord.Client()`), add these lines:

```js
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(let file of commandFiles) {
  let command = require('./commands/' + file);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

- And on your message event listener (assuming that you already have made some commands in the folder), replace your command if statement(s) with this:

```js
// you can use other expressions to check if the command is there
// the commandname in the client.commands.get is the filename without .js
if(message.content.startsWith("commandname")) client.commands.get("commandname").execute(message, args);
```

- Creating commands will be the process of creating JavaScript files in your commands folder. So in your commands folder, create a file (filename will be like "commandname.js" or something) and the content will be:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "commandname",
  description: "Command description here.",
  execute(message, args) {
    // Now you can do your command logic here
  }
}
```

I hope this helped! If it isn't clear, feel free to downvote.

Comment: Looking at your problem, it is most likely that you haven't put your command files inside the commands folder.